# I need to compare and dates and return how many days are left to expiry or how many days ago they expired

Tags: python, csv

I have never used Python before, coming from a Javascript background.

I need to loop through the array in the csv and compare it with the date in the today variable. Then return where each item is expired or valid. Also how many days are left to expiry or how many days ago they expired.

Any pointers?

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime(2020, 5, 2)

with open('./guarantees_end.csv', 'r') as f: 
    for line in f.readlines():
```

My csv data is compiled like below:

```
2020-06-23,Flat C

2020-07-31,2 Teal Close

2020-08-14,67 Pinkers Mead

2020-08-31,3 Acacia Road

2020-04-13,1 Manor Place
```

Comment: So, your question is about to read csv file and then compare with `today` variable?

Comment: Hi @dcariotti yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read today's date using:

```
import datetime    
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

My temp.csv contains:

```
2020-12-11, ABCD
2020-12-23, EFGH
2020-12-01, IJKL
2020-11-11, MNOP
```

To read from CSV you can use:

```
f = open('temp.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in csv_reader:
    product_date_str = str(row[0])
```

Now you can convert the date string (read from csv) to datetime.date object using:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
product_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(product_date_str, date_format).date()
```

Now you can get the date difference using:

```
diff = (today - product_date).days
```

And then you can use this diff to print or display whatever you want. For example:

```
if diff > 0:
    print('{} has already expired since {} days.'.format(row[1], abs(diff)))
elif diff < 0:
    print('{} will expire in next {} days.'.format(row[1], abs(diff)))
else:
    print('{} will expire today.'.format(row[1]))
```

So the complete code snippet would look like:

```
import  csv
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
with open('temp.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        product_date_str = str(row[0])
        date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
        product_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(product_date_str, date_format).date()
        diff = (today - product_date).days
        if diff > 0:
            print('{} has already expired since {} days.'.format(row[1], abs(diff)))
        elif diff < 0:
            print('{} will expire in next {} days.'.format(row[1], abs(diff)))
        else:
            print('{} will expire today.'.format(row[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I how would I implement it with the date  set as ``` today = datetime(2020, 5, 2) ``` I've tried it with that variable but it doesn't seem to work. Although it works with the variable ``` today = datetime(2020, 5, 2) ```

Comment: Sorry but both the variables that you commented are same... Can you please correct it and let me know your doubt again..
 Do you want to use a custom today date? If so then, you can do : today = datetime.datetime(2020,5,2).date() to use it in the above code..

Comment: I managed to get it working by using `today = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 2).date()` I just saw your above comment. I solved it the same way. Apologies of getting mixed up with the variable I must have copy and pasted the same line twice. Thank you for your help